# Exporting two different CSVs using ArcPy with ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, csv

I am using ArcGIS Desktop: ArcMap 10.6 with ArcPy Library (Python 2.7.14).

Here is a code snippet from a larger script:

```
out_dataset = 'Data'
arcpy.Sort_management(points, out_dataset, [[fields[11], 'ASCENDING']])
arcpy.management.CreateFolder('C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop', 'Points_Table_Export')
outLoc = 'C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\Points_Table_Export'
fms = arcpy.FieldMappings()
csv_fields = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
for field in csv_fields:
    fm = arcpy.FieldMap()
    fm.addInputField(out_dataset, field)
    fms.addFieldMap(fm)
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(out_dataset, outLoc, 'Temp.csv', '', fms)
df = pd.read_csv(outLoc + '\\Temp.csv')

# Removes Object_ID from first column
first_column = df.columns[0]
df = df.drop([first_column], axis=1)    
df.to_csv(outLoc + '\\Points.csv', index=False, header=False)   
# Delete the temp csv
os.remove(outLoc + '\\Temp.csv')
os.remove(outLoc + '\\Temp.txt.xml')
os.remove(outLoc + '\\schema.ini')
```

Is there a way to export a second .csv file, named 'Points2.csv' with different fields, ie `csv_fields_1 = ['5', '6', '7' '8']` within the same snippet?

Comment: Sure, build a function into your code.   https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp

Comment: Anything that needs to run for both CSVs goes into the function, then any variable that needs to change (input path, output path, list of field names, etc.) becomes an argument

Comment: This is a question purely about programming.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a list inside the list `csv_fields = ['1', '2', '3', '4']`, doint some like this:

```
csv_fields = [['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['5','6', '7', '8']]
```

and put a for outside of the principal loop:

```
out_dataset = 'Data'
arcpy.Sort_management(points, out_dataset, [[fields[11], 'ASCENDING']])
arcpy.management.CreateFolder('C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop', 'Points_Table_Export')
outLoc = 'C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\Points_Table_Export'
fms = arcpy.FieldMappings()
csv_fields_list = [['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['5','6', '7', '8']]
for csv_fields in csv_fields_list:
    for field in csv_fields:
        fm = arcpy.FieldMap()
        fm.addInputField(out_dataset, field)
        fms.addFieldMap(fm)
    arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(out_dataset, outLoc, 'Temp.csv', '', fms)
    df = pd.read_csv(outLoc + '\\Temp.csv')

    # Removes Object_ID from first column
    first_column = df.columns[0]
    df = df.drop([first_column], axis=1)    
    df.to_csv(outLoc + '\\Points.csv', index=False, header=False)   
    # Delete the temp csv
    os.remove(outLoc + '\\Temp.csv')
    os.remove(outLoc + '\\Temp.txt.xml')
    os.remove(outLoc + '\\schema.ini')
```